# $.post returns correct data with an extra newline character at the beginning

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a simple ajax call on login.php that performs basic validation.

If the user types a valid username, then checkuser.php returns 'Valid username' through an echo statement.

Now, when I alert the data element from the post request it shows 'Valid username'. But when testing equality with 'Valid username', it goes to the false part of the if statement, alerting 'fail'.

checkuser.php

```
include_once 'functions.php';
echo "Valid username";
```

login.php (minimal)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.post('checkuser.php', {user: 'validUser'},function(data) {
            $.trim(data);
            alert(data);
            if (data=='Valid username')
                alert('success');
            else
                alert('fail');
        });
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

I've used the jQuery trim function to no avail. Any idea why this may be happening?

---

So it turns out that the include statement preappended a \n to the $.post call because there were blank lines at the end of the file. The problem was solved by removing those blank lines after the ?> closing tag in the functions.php file.

Comment: do some debugging by log the output into the console before if statement by saying console.log(data); and find out what properties it contains. Then validate against prop value accordingly

Comment: It seems data comes with a \n character at the beginning.

Comment: So fix the PHP so you don't send that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google chrome you can check the response under the network tab when you use the Developer Tools.

However I would suggest you use the result parameter to check if the call was successful.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.post('checkuser.php', {user: 'validUser'},function(data, result) {            
            alert(data);
            if(result=='success')
                alert('success');
            else
                alert('fail');
        });
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

PS. Your original code works on my side. The only thing I added was php tags in your checkuser.php file

Comment: Your code works on my side, the only thing I added was php tags in your checkuser.php

Answer (score 0):

As for why your PHP code returns `\n` with the data, we'd need to see the code.

However, on why $.trim() doesn't work -- Notably, jQuery $.trim() won't remove newlines.  Instead, you could use Regex.  This will remove all newlines:

`textvar = textvar.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");`

Though Chris's implementation above seems like a better choice for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have blank lines at the end of your PHP script.